# UIViewController with XIB and custom view size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

i created a UIViewController subclass with a Xib interface..
i want force the width of view to a 257px. I change the size in IB in FREEFORM, and resize to 257px widht.

I put this log in viewcontrollerclass

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"width: %f",self.view.frame.size.width);
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    NSLog(@"width_changed: %f",self.view.frame.size.width);
}
```

and the log is

```
2013-10-09 14:14:18.966 TestApp[2008:a0b] width: 258.000000
2013-10-09 14:14:18.968 TestApp[2008:a0b] width_changed: 320.000000
```

why the width change? how can fix it?
the AutoResizingMask are disabled.

Thank you!

Comment: can you post more code of resizing?

Comment: Who initializes your view? You do it programmatically (e.g. `[myViewController alloc] initWithNib...` or did you put it inside another view in another xib?

Comment: I think this is an autolayout problem.. uncheck the autolayout property from the IB and see what you get..

Answer (score 0):

Force the frame of your view inside `viewDidLoad` with your width :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 257, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame));
}
```

Comment: is there some setting in the xib I blocks the automatic resize?

Comment: add a picture of your xib